# AWS PHP SDK - Polly Ignores Neural Engine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk, amazon-polly

I have no idea why AWS ignores the "neural" engine and outputs the standard voice only. I have tried other NTTS voices and other regions. Same thing over and over again. As you can see in the debug result `request.body was set to...`, the `'Engine' => 'neural'` setting is ignored and not showna. Please help. Thanks.

[SpeechSynthesisTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_StartSpeechSynthesisTask.html), [Polly Voices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/voicelist.html)

```
try {
    $result = $client->startSpeechSynthesisTask([
        'LanguageCode' => 'en-US',
        'Text' => 'Why do you ignore the neural engine?',
        'OutputFormat' => 'mp3',
        'OutputS3BucketName' => xyz-bucket,
        'OutputS3KeyPrefix' => 'polly-test/',
        'VoiceId' => 'Matthew',
        'Engine' => 'neural'
    ]);
    $taskId = $result['SynthesisTask']['TaskId'];
    print('<p>Task started: ' . $taskId . '</p>');
    var_dump($result);
    } catch (AwsException $e) {
        // output error message if fails
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo "\n";
```

debug results show:

`request.body was set to {"LanguageCode":"en-US","Text":"Why do you ignore the neural engine?","OutputFormat":"mp3","OutputS3BucketName":"xyz-bucket","OutputS3KeyPrefix":"polly-test\/","VoiceId":"Matthew"}`

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, when I used the exact same code, my request body was different:

```
{"LanguageCode":"en-US","Text":"Why do you ignore the neural engine?","OutputFormat":"mp3","OutputS3BucketName":0,"OutputS3KeyPrefix":"polly-test\/","VoiceId":"Matthew","Engine":"neural"}
```

For some reason the engine parameter is getting stripped from your input.  This may be because you're using an older version of the SDK before the parameter was introduced; this would have been added in `3.108.2`.  Which version of the SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I still get this problem now with `3.256`

If I request a `neural` output for the voice `Brian` then it just returns a standard output. I guess it's a bug?

However, if I request a neural output from `Matthew` then it works fine.

Edit...

It now works with `Brian` and `neural` - all I had to do was declare the `Engine` after the `VoiceId` in the array!